# Problem installing GRUB with dual boot Win7 on RAID

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7, raid

I use Linux at work and am pretty happy setting up and installing to new machines in several configurations, however I have to admit, this time I'm stumped!

I have a nice new PC with an SSD Raid in place. It currently has windows 7 installed, and I was able to successfully install ubuntu (12.04) from a live usb. When I reached the end I had the error

```
executing grub-install failed
```

I finished the install without installing GRUB expecting to be able to do this seperately after, I did some googling and came across the following advice:

Create a temp folder, and link to the linux partition. 
Run the following command "sudo grub-install --root-directory=/home/ubuntu/Temp /dev/mapper/[PARTITION HERE]"

in my case:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/home/ubuntu/Temp /dev/mapper/pdc_ifegdfjd5
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.

Auto-detection of a filesystem of /dev/mapper/pdc_ifegdfjd5 failed.
Try with --recheck.
If the problem persists please report this together with the output of "/usr/sbin   /grub-probe --device-map="/home/ubuntu/Temp/boot/grub/device.map" --target=fs -v  /home/ubuntu/Temp/boot/grub" to <bug-grub@gnu.org>
```

So I've run with --recheck and get the exact same error.

I'm not entire sure where to go from here, I've some more googling, but not getting any positive result.

The output of fdisk -l:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/pdc_ifegdfjd1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS   /exFAT
/dev/mapper/pdc_ifegdfjd2          206848   184526847    92160000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/mapper/pdc_ifegdfjd3       184527102   464843519   140158209    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/mapper/pdc_ifegdfjd5       184527104   431427327   123450112   83  Linux
/dev/mapper/pdc_ifegdfjd6       431427584   464843519    16707968   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Many thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Matt,

(updated from earlier answer)

I booted to a live cd (well USB) and followed these instructions to get boot repair running:

http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

After this I ran boot repair and simply used the automatic option. When it eventually got to installing grub (in a dos type windows) I selected the first windows 7 area to install it on (I think!)

After reboot things were ok and grub was booting.

Comment: nb: the system I am talking about in the guide is another one I have and I am not trying to boot from the raid drive on it (just in case you are confused by me seemingly having this fixed ;)

Comment: Hi Tentimes, 

Thanks for the response, it looks like a method I've not tried - I'm no longer in front of the system, as it was a friends system I was trying to convert to ubuntu - he's now 100 miles away, so I'll send the advice on, and see what we get back. 

Thanks again.